# How to make a two-column filter in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to make a two-column filter so that, for example, it displays all lines containing *X*, **OR** in column `A` **OR** in column `B`. If I just use the built-in filter and put an *X* in there, it only shows the lines that contain *X* **AND** in column `A` **AND** in column `B`. How can I implement an **OR** filter?

Source table

[image]

This is what I get:

[image]

This is what I need:

[image]

That is, *X* is contained either in column `A` **or** in column `B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the filter criteria are single-column specific, consider using a "helper" column.  In **C2** enter:

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(FIND("X",A2)), ISNUMBER(FIND("X",B2)))
```

and copy downward.

Then filter on column **C** looking for `TRUE`

Pre-filter:

[image]

post-filter:

[image]

Comment: It's a pity that this cannot be done through the built-in filter, I would not want to use any additional columns and formulas, but thanks for the answer anyway

Comment: @RoyalGoose  I suggest you re-consider.  Even a single "helper" column can tremendously increase the power and utility of AutoFilter.